# jq 1.6/oniguruma 5.9.6 throws "Regex failure: invalid pattern in look-behind" error

Tags: regex, jq, pcre, regex-lookarounds, negative-lookbehind

### Problem

I'm trying to use a `jq v1.6` filter that has a regex, which contains a negative look-behind and negative look-ahead expressions, but they are failing with `Regex failure: invalid pattern in look-behind`, even though the spec seems like it would be a valid expression.

The command I'm using is

```
$ jq -n '("baz", "foo baz", "bla baz", "baz bars") | test("(?<!foo |bars )baz(?! foo| bars)")'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Regex failure: invalid pattern in look-behind
```

It seems like `jq 1.6` is using the Onigurama library version 5.9.6 (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/61edf3fa93f6177ef099b1b0cb2b49813a35c546#diff-ea6712465e6d2ae84a07da73f4ad6e25, this seems the right script version because `jq 1.6` was released on Nov 2018, and the next commit for `compile-ios.sh` is until Dec 2019).

Now, Oniguruma 5.9.6 closest documentation I could find is from 5.9.1 (in https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/commit/65a9b1aa03c9bc2dc01b074295b9603232cb3b78# you can search for `negative look-behind`, line 221 of `doc/RE` file.

> (?<!subexp) negative look-behind
>
> Subexp of look-behind must be fixed character length.
> But different character length is allowed in top level
> alternatives only.
> ex. (?<=a|bc) is OK. (?<=aaa(?:b|cd)) is not allowed.
>
> In negative-look-behind, captured group isn't allowed,
> but shy group(?:) is allowed.

So it seems like my expression should work.

After testing a few things, I found out that this works:

```
jq -n '("baz", "foo baz", "bla baz", "baz bars") | test("(?<!foo|bar)baz(?! foo| bars)")'
```

The only difference is that the look-behind expression alternatives are fixed width, but the docs clearly state that top level alternatives are allowed to have variable width.

### Conclusion

It seems that for some reason, this particular version of `jq` does not support variable-width alternatives in a (negative) look-behind expression, even though the spec says nothing about this.

### Note

I suspect something is going on with the particular `jq` build I installed, because if I try to run the regex example in https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#RegularexpressionsPCRE in also get an error:

```
$ jq -n '("test", "TEst", "teST", "TEST") | test( "(?i)te(?-i)st" )'
jq: error (at <unknown>): Regex failure: invalid group name <>
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your current library version is limited to fixed-width lookbehind patterns, you can't do much about it.

In your case, since you are using negative lookbehinds, you can do without alternation, just split the lookbehind into two:

```
(?<!foo )(?<!bars )baz(?! foo| bars)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Then, you do not have to care how many chars each lookbehind has to check.